# Find all $p$ is prime number such that Both $p+14$ and $p+20$ are Prime number.

Tags: prime-numbers

Find all  $p$ is prime number such that Both  $p+14$ and $p+20$ are Prime number.
I knomw $p=3,p=17,p=23$, but I can't to show that is that all.

Comment: I doubt that there is a finite number of them. Type `x=1;x=x+1;x<10000;x;isprime(x) and isprime(x+14) and isprime(x+20)` into https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM to get all primes under 10000 satisfying this condition.

Comment: The (generalized) Bunyakovsky conjecture predicts infinite many such primes , but it is open whether this is actually the case.

Comment: A large example is $$10^{100}+1890007$$